# Apache2/Laravel responding 301 on some agents

Tags: laravel, apache2, router, hotspot

I have wifidog installed on a TP-LINK
(openwrt 18.06.2)

I have wifidog-auth-laravel installed on a OVH Debian
github /wifidog/wifidog-auth-laravel)

If I use curl, chrome and wget; I get the pong response for the authetication url

But if wifidog attempts to get the pong response I get a 301 Permanantly moved response.

How can that be?

```
[7][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](centralserver.c:302) Level 1: Connecting to auth server example.com:80
[7][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](centralserver.c:331) Level 1: Successfully connected to auth server example.com:80
[7][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](centralserver.c:141) Unlocking config
[7][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](centralserver.c:141) Config unlocked
[7][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](centralserver.c:147) Connected to auth server
[6][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](wd_util.c:116) AUTH_ONLINE status became ON
[7][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](simple_http.c:77) Sending HTTP request to auth server: [GET /ping/?gw_id=EC086B35444C&sys_uptime=1820&sys_memfree=6096&sys_load=0.70&wifidog_uptime=3 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: WiFiDog 1.2.1
Host: example.com

]

[7][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](simple_http.c:87) Reading response
[7][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](simple_http.c:111) Read 725 bytes
[7][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](simple_http.c:124) HTTP Response from 

Server: [HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 20 May 2019 13:44:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Location: http://example.com/ping?gw_id=EC086B35444C&sys_uptime=1820&sys_memfree=6096&sys_load=0.70&wifidog_uptime=3
Content-Length: 415
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://example.com/ping?gw_id=EC086B35444C&amp;sys_uptime=1820&amp;sys_memfree=6096&amp;sys_load=0.70&amp;wifidog_uptime=3">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
]
[4][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](ping_thread.c:191) Auth server did NOT say Pong!
[7][Mon May 20 13:44:54 2019][5977](firewall.c:140) Marking auth server down
```

Comment: There seems to be an `.htaccess` rule that strips trailing slashes. That's very common and you should try to deal with it by e.g. following the redirect or ensuring your request does not have trailing slashes e.g. change `/ping/` to `/ping`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
The Wifidog userAgent formed the url different from the other user agents:

a workaround is in the wifidog.conf

```
AuthServer {
    Hostname example.com
    SSLAvailable yes
    Path /
    PingScriptPathFragment ping?
    LoginScriptPathFragment login?
    PortalScriptPathFragment portal?
    MsgScriptPathFragment gw_message.php?
    AuthScriptPathFragment auth?
}
```